# Caching entity manager's (hibernate session) find query

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpql, ehcache

I am currently setting up query caches for my JPQL (Named) queries.
However, some methods are implemented using entityManager.find(clazz, id) and i cannot find a way to make it work as a cached query.
Since this is a module that is read-only I would like to set caches for all queries. Is it possible to define a ehcache region for em.find() method without manualy typing named SELECTs for each entity?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the persistant unit has 
    property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ALL"

in it.

Comment: Tried it now, does not help. Anyway, ideally I would like to set regions for those queries.